# Counting the numbers of factors for values smaller than a variable in R

Tags: r, counting, summary

I have the following R data which I would like to process by counting for each factor the number of times it has been seen for values smaller than in x.

```
structure(list(variable = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), x = c(0, 0.01, 0.03, 0.05, 0.33, 
0.38, 0.02, 0.03, 0.1, 0.15, 0.41, 0.42, 0.38, 0.07, 0.32, 0.05, 
0.04)), .Names = c("variable", "x"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17"))
```

I would end up with a data frame as follows:

```
   x A B C
0 00 0 1 0
0.01 0 2 0
0.02 0 3 0
0.03 1 4 0
0.04 1 5 0
0.05 3 5 0
0.07 3 5 1
and so on
```

I haven't found anything straight forward so far so I would be very grateful for help.

Comment: That does the same thing as table using `table(x,variable)` but I want the number of times A's, B's and C's have been seen for values smaller than 0.01, then 0.02 ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
tbl1 <- table(df1[2:1])
res <- apply(tbl1, 2, cumsum)
head(res, 7)
#     variable
#       A B C
#  0    0 1 0
#  0.01 0 2 0
#  0.02 0 3 0
#  0.03 1 4 0
#  0.04 1 5 0
#  0.05 3 5 0
#  0.07 3 5 1
```

Or a one-line code would be (from @David Arenburg's comments)

```
 apply(table(df1), 1, cumsum)
```